# Can you use sundried anchovies for myeolchi yuksu (Korean anchovy broth)?

Tags: broth

I am wanting to make myeolchi yuksu (Korean anchovy broth) which is based on dried anchovies. My local Korean supermarket only has these Chinese sourced dried anchovies, which were also labelled as sundried anchovies. They look quite different from the ones in the [recipe I was following](https://www.koreanbapsang.com/how-to-make-anchovy-broth-for-korean/).

Would there be any issue using these?

[image: photo of the dried anchovies packet]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

It looks like the Korean dried anchovies are very similar to the ones you have, just with the skins, heads, and guts removed, then flattened or 'spatchcocked'. For a fish stock like this, the specific type of fish you use won't matter too much. Also, I noticed the ingredients on your pack include salt, so you might want to taste and adjust the salt levels in wherever you're using the stock.